# Working with output of PI break sets of numbers, remove numbers

Tags: excel, output, formula

I have a list of numbers outputted from a review of PI (the number 3.1415926535897932384......)

It looks like this:

```
8850838032 0621312483 8327044318 1257233570 9958940293 1391776730 2923888859 5836058683 5192760238 4694561699 : 110000000001
9312900154 4838526183 9375914106 9846458403 5847003707 2451543553 9394699328 5157228504 5434270590 6509736487 : 110000000002
1284090545 3175919151 4159855781 3410862263 2549812643 7600394225 7109902021 0694219181 6542482795 7164656581 : 110000000003
1367977800 8915483236 6072599505 1466161901 1090687303 7608155585 3289637107 6490574006 0401938787 7258319674 : 110000000004
```

- the list is in notepad (.txt file)
- set of 10 digits per number
- set of 10 numbers per line (10 digits per x 10 numbers per line)
- reference number at the end ( the : 110000000001 : 110000000002 etc numbers)

Heres what I would like to do:

- to remove the reference numbers first ( the : 110000000001 : 110000000002 etc numbers)
- to break each set of 10 digits into 5 sets of 2 digit numbers, with each 2 digit number appearing on a seperate line of its own - 0621312483 to 06 21 31 24 83
- from this I want to remove all 2 digit numbers over 26, so that I am only left with numbers from 01 - 26 - from 06 21 31 24 83 to 06 21 24

Comment: I would use VBA to read the file, parse it according to your rules, and output on the worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Seems might only be (have been?) required the one time so may be simpler to give the results:

```
6   21  24  4   18  12  23  2   13  23  5   2   16          
12  1   6   3   0   7   24  22  4   5   9                   
12  9   5   10  22  25  26  0   25  9   20  21  6   21      
13  0   15  5   14  16  19  1   10  3   8   15  7   6   4   1
```

(which don't end in the way indicated in the question) but the process was, assuming `8850838032 ....` in A1:

1. Text to Columns with `:` as the delimiter, delete ColumnB.
2. `="'"&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))` in ColumnB copied down to B4.
3. Select ColumnB, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top.
4. Text to Columns on ColumnB with Fixed width (first one character then every second).
5. Delete ColumnB.
6. Select B1:AY4, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

   `=B1>26`

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select a colour fill, OK, OK.

7. Select and Copy B1:AY4, say to AZ2, with Paste Special, Transpose.
8. Filter ColumnAZ by colour to select those coloured and blank out each selection then reselecting `(Select All)`.
9. Repeat for ColumnsBA, BB and BC.
10. Tidy up to suit, eg by selecting AZ>BC, HOME > Editing - Find & Select, Go To Special, Blanks, select, Delete..., Shift cells up and then moving the contents of BA under AZ, etc and deleting what is not required.
    .